# iCloud Core Data Migration

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I am developing an iOS 7 only application and I am fairly new to iCloud and Core data.
My assumption is that the user always wants to use iCloud for Backup if possible. That is why I set up my persistence store as follows:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

 if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {

      return __persistentStoreCoordinator;

 }

 NSURL *storeURL = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]

                                URLByAppendingPathComponent:storeNameWithoutFileExtension isDirectory:NO]

                               URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];

 NSError *error = nil;

 __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];



 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                                    selector:@selector(persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitiousContentChanges:)

                                                         name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification

                                                      object:__persistentStoreCoordinator];



 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                                    selector:@selector(storesWillChange:)

                                                         name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification

                                                      object:__persistentStoreCoordinator];



 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                                    selector:@selector(storesDidChange:)

                                                         name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification

                                                      object:__persistentStoreCoordinator];





 NSDictionary *options = @{ NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,

                                  NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : storeNameWithoutFileExtension, };

// NSPersistentStoreRebuildFromUbiquitousContentOption

// NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,

// NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,



 if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType

                                                             configuration:nil

                                                                         URL:storeURL

                                                                    options:options

                                                                       error:&error])

 {

      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

      abort();

 }



 return __persistentStoreCoordinator;

}
```

With this setup I always immediately start using the folders under Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport even if the user is not logged in to iCloud (using "local" folder).

As you can see I am registering for Notifications.

- Why are the added and removed persistence stores in the arrays of the keys NSAddedPersistentStoresKey and NSRemovedPersistentStoresKey in the NSNotifications of NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification and NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification always identical e.g. for the case account added?
  One would expect that the notification contains the removed persistence store and the newly added. So they should not be the same. But unfortunately they are always the same.

The current behaviour is if I switch accounts or log out of an account or log in to a new account the app always starts with the associated store or a new one if there was none before. My desired behaviour would be that the app always migrates the data to the new store. E.g.: User is not logged in to iCloud and starts using my app. He creates data which is saved under local in Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport. Now he turns on iCloud. Now I want the local data to be migrated to the cloud. Currently this is not happening.
In which method do I have to implement the migration and how exactly do I implement it? Can I use the method "migratePersistentStore"? I tried to use the following code in NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification but to no avail:

```
 - (void)storesDidChange:(NSNotification *)n {

 // refresh user interface
 switch ([[n.userInfo objectForKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeKey] integerValue]) {

      case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountAdded : {

           NSLog(@"NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountAdded migrate");


           NSError *error = nil;

           NSURL *storeURL = ((NSPersistentStore *)asdf[0]).URL;

           NSDictionary *options = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,

                                            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,

                                            NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : storeNameWithoutFileExtension, };

           NSPersistentStore *asdfasdf = [__persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:self.oldStore toURL:storeURL options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];
      }

      break;

      case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountRemoved :

           NSLog(@"NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountRemoved");



           break;

      case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeContentRemoved : {

           NSLog(@"NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeContentRemoved migrate");

           NSError *error = nil;

           NSURL *storeURL = ((NSPersistentStore *)asdf[0]).URL;

           NSDictionary *options = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,

                                            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,

                                            NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : storeNameWithoutFileExtension, };

           NSPersistentStore *asdfasdf = [__persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:self.oldStore toURL:storeURL options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

      }

      break;

      case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted :

           NSLog(@"NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted");

           NSLog(@"initial import");



           break;

      default :

           break;

 }

}
```

The variable oldStore was set in the NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification since I could not rely on the NSNotification and its keys NSAddedPersistentStoresKey and NSRemovedPersistentStoresKey because as previously states both arrays always contain the same stores as previously described.

- In which method/at what point would I implement deduplication code? Can I do it in one of the notifications?
- For which usecase do I have to use NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption? How does that option work exactly?

A weird behaviour I have seen while playing around with my app is that if the user is not logged in to iCloud. When I bring my app to the background and I log out of iCloud and go back to my App the NSNotifications I get are of type NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeContentRemoved. I would expect NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountRemoved. If I then bring the app to background and back up again I get NSNotifications with type NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountRemoved. But unfortunately NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification and NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification are always fired for the usecase when the user is not logged in to the iCloud and the app is running and the user brings the app to the background and then back to the foreground and I get NSNotifications with type NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountRemoved. And this always happens.
- Why is that?

To make my used code complete here is my code for the NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification and the NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification and a couple other functions:

```
- (void)storesWillChange:(NSNotification *)n {

 NSLog(@"storesWillChange");

 NSArray *pStores = self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores;
 NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];



 switch ([[n.userInfo objectForKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeKey] integerValue]) {

      case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountAdded : {

           NSLog(@"NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountAdded");

           self.oldStore = pStores[0];

      }

      break;

      case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountRemoved :

           NSLog(@"NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountRemoved");



           break;

      case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeContentRemoved :

           NSLog(@"NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeContentRemoved");

           self.oldStore = pStores[0];

           break;

      case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted :

           NSLog(@"NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted");

           NSLog(@"initial import");



           break;

      default :

           break;

 }

 [moc performBlockAndWait:^{

       NSError *error = nil;

       if ([moc hasChanges]) {

            [moc save:&error];

       }

       [moc reset];

  }];


 // reset user interface


 }




- (void)persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitiousContentChanges:(NSNotification    *)changeNotification {

 NSLog(@"*** Incoming iCloud Data ***");

 NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];



 [moc performBlock:^{

       [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:changeNotification];

  }];

 }




 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

 if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {

      return __managedObjectContext;

 }



 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

 if (coordinator != nil) {

      __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

 //          __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

      [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

      [__managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

 }

 return __managedObjectContext;

 }


 - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

 if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {

      return __managedObjectModel;

 }

 NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:dataModelName withExtension:@"momd"];

 __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

 return __managedObjectModel;

 }
```

So basically what I want to accomplish is that the user has the same data no matter which iCloud account he is using even if it is "local".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check this link for sample code and video demonstrating iCloud sync'ing and store migration when user changes their iCloud settings. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To migrate data from one Core Data store to another (whether using iCloud or not) use the `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` method of `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

However, ensuring your data is always the same (migrated) between all iCloud accounts is:

- likely to be difficult (at least I don't know how you'd do it).
- probably not what your users want. It makes sense for each iCloud account to have its own data.

As of iOS 7 iCloud Core Data has been significantly improved and vastly simplified (for developers). One of the simplifications is that Core Data now transparently handles iCloud account changes and local fallback stores, and creation of a "local" store if you open a ubiquitous store but the user is not logged into iCloud.

Unfortunately, this "local" store is treated as if it were an (dummy) iCloud account, so migrating from it to another (real) iCloud account is tricky. Because of this, it's preferable to have a "Use iCloud: Yes/No" option in your app. If the user chooses "No" then create a true local (not iCloud enabled) store (stored in the `Documents` folder). Now when the user changes the iCloud option in your app, you have the option to migrate this local store to the iCloud enabled store (using `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:`), and vice-versa if the user switches from iCloud to Local.

The other question you asked was:

> For which usecase do I have to use NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption? How does that option work exactly?

The options `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` are used to migrate a store to an updated **data model** (e.g. if you add fields to an entity) and have nothing to do with migrating from one store to another. They are not relevant to the problem you want to solve here.

Comment: What's the benefit of having a true local store versus "dummy" iCloud account when user have iCloud disabled?

Comment: @LocPham the benefit is that your app can easily access this non-iCloud local store, regardless of whether iCloud is enabled or not, thus allowing the user to migrate data from/to it if they choose. The "dummy" iCloud account store is not accessible from your app if the user has iCloud enabled with a real account. This is because it is treated as belonging to a real iCloud account and your app doesn't have access to the iCloud store of other iCloud accounts.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend not using iCloud+CoreData in iOS6. There are many bugs. Read this:

http://www.theverge.com/2013/3/26/4148628/why-doesnt-icloud-just-work

http://www.zdnet.com/developers-give-apple-an-icloud-ultimatum-fix-it-by-june-7000013495/

**EDIT**

In iOS7 seems to have improved somewhat but developers say that have issues when change the model version. :(

Comment: That was before iOS7. In iOS7 iCloud sync works well.

Comment: This is indeed out of date for iOS7

Comment: iCloud Sync still fails regularly in iOS 7 and should still be avoided if at all possible.  I now spend the majority of my time troubleshooting core-data iCloud issues instead of working on new features and/or apps, and that still applies to iOS 7.

Comment: @ChristopherKing Agree, currently I have an issues after changing model version.